# Mapping array values to hash with incrementing key name

Tags: arrays, ruby, hashmap

I have an array of strings that are hex color codes like so:

```
["#121427", "#291833", "#4B2E4D", "#5D072F", "#BB2344", "#ED9F90"]
```

and I want to convert them into a hash with distinct key name where there is a distinct name "color" and then a integer value which increments as it transverses the array adding them like so:

```
{"color1" => "#121427", "color2" => "#291833", "color3" => "#4B2E4D", "color4" => "#5D072F", "color5" => "#BB2344", "color6" => "#ED9F90"}
```

The integer value can be 0 based or 1 based, it doesn't matter which ever is cleaner.

I've tried using the `map` method along with the `to_h` method, although I cannot figure out how to create an incremental key name as described.

Comment: Perhaps use the COUNT() function? So the name becomes "color" . count(<ARRAY>)-1? Then as you add in the new colors, the name changes accordingly.

Comment: When you give an example, it's helpful to assign a variable to each input object (e.g., `arr = ["#121427",...]`). That way, readers can refer to the variable in comments and answers without having to define it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not too hard to do this using the [`each_with_index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index) method which is zero-indexed by default:

```
Hash[colors.each_with_index.map { |c, i| [ 'color%d' % i, c ] }]
```

You were close with `map`, you just needed to expand it into value/index pairs.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible way:

```
colors.each_with_object({}).with_index(1){|(e, h), i| h["color#{i}"] = e}
```

It uses:

- [`Enumerable#each_with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) to skip one temporary array and modify the resulting hash directly
- [`Enumerator#with_index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index) to also supply an auto-incrementing integer (it can even start from 1)

Answer (score 0):

If `arr` is your array, you could do this:

```
idx = 1.step
  # => #<Enumerator: 1:step> 
arr.each_with_object({}) { |s,h| h["color#{idx.next}"] = s }
  #=> {"color1"=>"#121427", "color2"=>"#291833", "color3"=>"#4B2E4D",
  #    "color4"=>"#5D072F", "color5"=>"#BB2344", "color6"=>"#ED9F90"}
```